# Using react-bootstrap-typeahead - Text is being blurry

Tags: reactjs, blur, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using [React Bootstrap Typeahead](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-typeahead) package in my project, and I encountered an issue when the text is being blurry.
Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-payne-n4y9e6
2. Start type "Alabama-Alabama-Alabama".
3. Text is blurry in the end.
4. If you don't get it, just type "Alabama-Alabama-Alabama" and try to delete some characters.
5. You will see something like this: 
   [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5759067/218279942-3481e6d0-204d-457e-80c4-578d2f1fb6e3.png]

I already opened a ticket about this [issue](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/issues/761), but I was wondering if someone has a solution for this until an official fix? Thanks.

Comment: Did you purposely create a long string that doesn't break as an example? Because if so then I would edit my response - but also I don't think there's anything you can do other than create a PR to fix it - or wait for them to fix it.

Comment: Yes, It's a long string from the propose of the example.

Answer (score 1):

In your JSON file, you have the following:

```js
{
  label:
    'Alabama-Alabama-Alabama-Alabama-Alabama-Alabama-Alabama-Alabama-Alabama-Alabama-Alabama-Alabama-Alabama-Alabama-Alabama-',
  population: 4780127,
  capital: 'Montgomery',
  region: 'South',
},
```

Compare to [this working `react-boostrap-typeahead` sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-water-ymy14m). Probably delete that issue.

Comment: The "Alabama-Alamaba" is an example of a long string without breaks.